# knife vault refresh command cannot search query

Tags: chef-infra, knife, chef-vault

I tried to refresh vault with `knife vault refresh` command, but invalid search query error is occurred.

How do I fix it?

```
 
$ knife vault create devvault vaultitem --file private.key -M client
```

$ knife vault show devvault vaultitem -M client
file-content: secret

file-name:    private.key
id:           vaultitem

$ knife vault rotate all keys -M client
Rotating keys for: devvault vaultitem

$ knife vault refresh devvault vaultitem -M client
ERROR: The data in your request was invalid
Response: invalid search query: '[]'

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved it. 
This is necessary.

`$ knife vault update devvault vaultitem -S 'chef_environment:dev' -M client`